# Using qmake without Qt Overhead?

Tags: qt, ubuntu-16.04, qmake, build-tools

We have some smaller libraries we use in our bigger project quite often.

Still we compile and run the unit tests of these smaller libraries as independent CI Jobs.

Most of these libs use QMake as buildtool, not using Qt in any way. And we started to move our CI-Jobs into docker containers. Now I realized that I always have to get qt5-default (on Ubuntu 16) for qmake to work. Is this intended? This gives quite a signifacant overhead. Does anybody know a way, to use qmake on Ubuntu 16 wihtout getting the whole Qt instalation on board?

Comment: `qmake` is part of `qt5-qmake`. As `qmake` is used to build Qt itself it should be able to work without `qt5-default`. Be sure to have `CONFIG -= qt` in your pro files. If you already tried that, can you tell what does not work when you do not have `qt5-default` installed, do you have any error message?

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need Qt installed for qmake to work. The reason why you need `qt5-default` is that most linux distributions provide both Qt5 and Qt4, which have the same binaries, for example they both have a version of `qmake`, which would both get installed to `/usr/bin`. In order to fix that problem Qt5 installs to `/usr/lib/.../qt5` and Qt4 to `/usr/lib/.../qt4`, and the `qt5-default` package creates symlinks from there to `/usr/bin`

For Ubuntu , `...` is `x86_64-linux-gnu`!

You can choose between:

1. Install only the `qt5-qmake` package in your docker container and create a symlink `/usr/bin/qmake` -> `/usr/lib/.../qt5`.*
2. Specify the full path to the qmake binary when building your software, inside your {travis, gitlab, jenkins} CI config
3. Add `/usr/lib/.../qt5/bin` to your `$PATH`

* The proper place for a manually created symlink would actually be `/usr/local/bin` because if you have the symlink in `/usr/bin`, installing `qt5-default` package would fail because the symlink `qt5-default` wants to create would already exist. However, you are in a docker container and can actually control whether `qt5-default` gets installed, and if you create the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` you have to make sure to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH`, which is overkill for that scenario.